# Append Character to String in Swift

Tags: string, swift, append, character

I'm trying to append Character to String using "+=", but It doesn't really work.
Once I tried with append method, it works. I just wonder why it is.
The compiler says "string is not identical to Unit8".

```
let puzzleInput = "great minds think alike"
var puzzleOutput = " "
for character in puzzleInput {

    switch character {
        case "a", "e", "i", "o", "u", " ":
        continue

    default:
        // error : doesn't work
        puzzleOutput += character
        //puzzleOutput.append(character)
    }
}
println(puzzleOutput)
```

Comment: FYI, it will work if you make `character` a `String` first: `puzzleOutput += String(character)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

20140818, Apple updated:

Updated the Concatenating Strings and Characters section to reflect the fact that String and Character values can no longer be combined with the addition operator (+) or addition assignment operator (+=). These operators are now used only with String values. Use the String type’s append method to append a single Character value onto the end of a string.

[Document Revision History 2014-08-18](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/RevisionHistory.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH40-XID_1636)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried out with puzzleOutput += "\(character)". And it works.

Comment: @Toshi puzzleOutput += "(\character)" should also work.

Comment: oh yeah I meant puzzleOutput += "(\character)" . Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

To append a `Character` to a `String` in Swift you can do something similar to the following:

```
var myString: String = "ab"
let myCharacter: Character = "c"
let myStringChar: String = "d"

myString += String(myCharacter) // abc
myString += myStringChar // abcd
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated version

```
let puzzleInput = "great minds think alike"
var puzzleOutput = ""
for character in puzzleInput.characters {
  switch character {
  case "a", "e", "i", "o", "u", " ":
   continue
  default:
    puzzleOutput += String(character)
  }
}
print(puzzleOutput)
// prints "grtmndsthnklk"
```